# Converting UN locations `coordinates` to lat and lng

Tags: python, coordinates

I have coordinates from the UNLOCATION dataset, that look like this: `4230N 00131E`.

According to their site, this is how it should be processed:
https://service.unece.org/trade/locode/Service/LocodeColumn.htm#Coordinates

> This column contains the geographical coordinates (latitude/longitude) of the location, if there is any.
>
> In order to avoid unnecessary use of non-standard characters and space, the following standard presentation is used:
>
> 0000lat 00000long
>
> (lat - Latitude: N or S ; long – Longitude: W or E, only one digit, capital letter)
>
> Where the last two rightmost digits refer to minutes and the first two or three digits refer to the degrees for latitude and longitude respectively. In addition, you must specify N or S for latitude and W or E for longitude, as appropriate.

I'm trying to convert it easily to lat,lng format, preferably through python.

I found the `latlon3` package and it requires a string format for this one,
So once I'm splitting `4230N 00131E` to `4230N` and `00131E`, I tried to present it as `d%%m%%H` but it doesn't work.

What am I missing, or how can I turn this string into lat and long easily?

Comment: Do you want the lat/lng like here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marek5050/UN-Locode-with-Timezone/master/data/easy_allCountries.csv python scripts https://github.com/marek5050/UN-Locode-with-Timezone/tree/master/scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I wrote this function:

```
def convert_unlocation_to_lat_lng(unlocation_coordinates: str) -> Tuple[Optional[float], Optional[float]]:
    # Split the input string into latitude and longitude parts
    coordinates = unlocation_coordinates.split(" ")
    if not coordinates[0]:
        return None, None
    lat_str = coordinates[0]
    lng_str = coordinates[1]

    # Extract latitude and longitude values
    lat_numbers = lat_str[:-1]
    lat_deg = int(lat_numbers[:-2])
    lat_min = int(lat_numbers[-2:])
    lng_numbers = lng_str[:-1]
    lng_deg = int(lng_numbers[:3])
    lng_min = int(lng_numbers[3:])

    # Determine direction of latitude and longitude
    lat_dir = 'N' if lat_str.endswith('N') else 'S'
    lng_dir = 'E' if lng_str.endswith('E') else 'W'

    # Calculate latitude and longitude in decimal format
    latitude = lat_deg + lat_min / 60
    longitude = lng_deg + lng_min / 60

    # Adjust latitude and longitude based on direction
    if lat_dir == 'S':
        latitude *= -1
    if lng_dir == 'W':
        longitude *= -1

    return latitude, longitude
```